# BabelJS : Why transpilation is not working?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

I want to use babelJs to transpile javascript source from es6 ( or es7 ) to es5. So i created a project. Here my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my front end app",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.10.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-js": "babel app/src/js -d app/libs/",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I create a javascript file :

```
var sayHello = name => {
    return "Hello: " + name;
};
var result = sayHello("Sandeep"),
    message = document.createElement("H1");
message.innerText = result;
document.body.appendChild(message);
```

When i run my task build-js , the output file contains the same content that input file. The transpilation did not happen. Is there anything to do else ?
Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation, or any tutorials, on Babel. Information for using it is readily available across the web. Hint: presets.

Comment: Add a `.babelrc` with the settings you want.